# retrieving information from inherited objects

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, operator-overloading

I am trying to implement a hierarchy of inherited objects from simpler to complexer ones, doing it  in such a way that the objects have as much object oriented features as possible, but I fill that this effort could be improved in many ways. Any sugestion is very welcome. In particular I don't know how to use the inheritance features i a safe way to solve the following issues:

1. The object Atom contains a vector of objects BasisFunction that was inherited from the simpler object Contraction. But in Atom I need to have access to the information contained in the vectors zeta and C of each BasisFunction. How to modify this to make it possible?
2. Are all the objects in the hierarchy copyable? How can I introduce object oriente features?
3. At the end I want to have a molecular singleton. How it could be defined?
4. I am concerned with performance of this approach to the implementation. Where it could be improved?

At this point I'll show the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;


class Contraction{
protected:
  vector<double> zeta;
  vector<double> c;
  vec A;
public:
  Contraction(){} /*contructor*/
 Contraction(vector<double> Zeta,vector<double> C, vec a):zeta(Zeta),c(C),A(a){}
 /*contructor*/
  ~Contraction(){} /*destructor*/

  bool deepcopy(const Contraction& rhs) {
    bool bResult = false;
    if(&rhs != this) {
      this->zeta=rhs.zeta;
      this->c=rhs.c;
      this->A=rhs.A;
      bResult = true;
    }
    return bResult;
  }

 public: 
  Contraction(const Contraction& rhs) { deepcopy(rhs); }
  Contraction& operator=(const Contraction& rhs) { deepcopy(rhs); return *this; }

};


class BasisFunction: public Contraction{
 protected:
  vector<int> n;
  vector<int> l;
  vector<int> m;

  bool deepcopy(const BasisFunction& rhs) {
    bool bResult = false;
    if(&rhs != this) {
      this->zeta=rhs.zeta;
      this->c=rhs.c;
      this->A=rhs.A;
      this->n=rhs.n;
      this->l=rhs.l;
      this->m=rhs.m;

      bResult = true;
    }
    return bResult;
  }

 public:
  BasisFunction(){};/*How to define this constructor to initialize the inherited elements too?*/
  ~BasisFunction(){};

};


class Atom{
 protected:
  int Z;
  vec R;   ///Position
  vec P;   ///Momentum
  vec F;   ///Force
  double mass;
  vector<BasisFunction> basis;
 public:
  /*Here I need to define a function that uses the information in vectors c_i and zeta_i of the vector basis, how could it be achieved?*/
};



vector<Atom> Molecule; /*I nedd transform this in a singleton, how?*/
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be better to ask this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How to modify this to make it possible? You should make protected fields of `Contraction` public or to make Getter/Setter methods in `Contraction` to acess this fileds, or rework all hierarchy of your classes to have this fields exactly there where they are needed.
2. Are all the objects in the hierarchy copyable? How can I introduce object oriente features? 
   There is no private copy constructors/assign operators in your classes and they don't have raw pointers to data in them, so they can be safe copied.
3. At the end I want to have a molecular singleton. How it could be
       defined? 
   You can't receive singleton from vector Molecule, because this is containter of objects not object itself. And there is no need in singleton here because you really can have only one "Molecule" named vector in scope. However if you want signleton to hold molecule data you should add a class shell to it:

```html
class Molecule
{
public:
    static Molecule & Instance() { static Molecule instance; return instance; }
    const vector<Atom> & GetMyData() const { return data; }
    vector<Atom> & GetMyData() { return data; }
private:
    Molecule() {};
    Molecule(const Molecule & rhs);
    const Molecule & operator=(const Molecule & rhs);
        
    vector<Atom> data;
};
```

It's classic Meyers's singleton realization.

4. I am concerned with performance of this approach to the
       implementation. Where it could be improved?
   To improve perfomance you need to remove all on every algorithm step processing virtual functions calls and indirections. In your code it means that you really shouldn't implement get/set methods in your base classes because now they are logically structs - just ordered data holders. If you will often look into zeta, c and other fields you must have direct access there.

Comment: with C++11, you may use `=delete` for copy constructor

Comment: Yes, but I don't see C++11 badge on topic starter question.

Comment: What's the reason for returning a non-const ref to `static` variable?

Comment: You may want to change data sometimes. So Molecule::Instance().GetMyData() will suit for this. If you had static const Molecule & Instance() it would have been impossible.